# Best way to handle boolean flags

Tags: java

I have a situation where i have many boolean flags to maintain in the code.

Below is the situation -

I have 6 flags for now flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6.

These flags gets toggled in the program. Now, these flags may increase and i am not liking the code with so many flags.

I thought of using a boolean array in a nested class, Something like this -

```
    private static class Flag{

    private static boolean[] flags = new boolean[]{false,false,false,false,false,false,false};

    private static void enableFlag1(){
        flags[0] = true;
    }

    private static void disableFlag1(){
        flags[0] = true;
    } //... So on for each flag

}
```

But here i will have to write methods for each flag.I liked this approach for fewer flag as it abstracts the user from the internal boolean array represention but for many flags it seems to be a problem.
Please assist as to what is the best method to do it?

Comment: Why not pass in the flag number as an `int` argument (as the index to the `flags` array)?

Comment: or use `java.util.BitSet`

Comment: Have you considered a Map<String, Boolean>

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ...Didn't use as i thought it would make it very much crude. If that be the case i can have a boolean array in the same class (instead of nested class) and can manipulate it directly e.g. flags[0] = true

Comment: @wero read somewhere that for few flags boolean array gives better performance than bit set.

Comment: The advantage of using a map rather than an array is that the purpose of the flag is explicit with its name in the map where as you have to implicitly know the position of the desired flag in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job for a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

```
static final BitSet flags = new BitSet(7);

static void enableFlag(int i) {
    flags.set(i);
}

static void disableFlag(int i) {
    flags.set(i, false);
} 

static boolean checkFlag(int i) {
    return flags.get(i);
}
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that the meaning of the flag is not explicitly named, you have to know the meaning by the position.

Comment: @bhspencer agree. But in OP question names are `flag1`, `flag2` etc, which means that only numeric index matters.

Comment: Thats a fair point and presumably the OP could come up with more meaningful names.

Comment: @bhspencer of course they could. But they don't :) But even for meaningful names it is better to use `int` constants or `enum`, not `String`.

Comment: Right but if you are going to the trouble to define a bunch of named int const then you might as well just have named boolean members of your class.

Comment: @bhspencer the difference is in that your code won't compile with wrongly spelled int constant or enum, but with wrongly spelled string it will silently compile and run until the first NPE.

Comment: Thanks..I have posted my answer as well which contains input from your post also.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for this purpose.

EnumSets are internally implemented bits in an array of longs, using the `ordinal()` value of the enum, which is very efficient, giving it similar performance characteristics as the [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), except with more type safety and arguably more legible.

For example, given this enum:

```
enum Features {
  FEATURE1, FEATURE2, FEATURE3
}
```

You can create an EnumSet with the appropriate flags like so:

```
Set<Features> flags = EnumSet.of(FEATURE1);
```

This will allow for feature testing like so:

```
flags.contains(FEATURE2); // false
flags.contains(FEATURE1); // true
```

Or, for multiple tests you can compare to a second set:

```
Set<Features> requiredFlags = EnumSet.of(FEATURE1, FEATURE2);

flags.containsAll(requiredFlags); // false

Set<Features> allFlags = EnumSet.allOf(Features.class);
allFlags.containsAll(requiredFlags); // true
```

Note that `EnumSet`s behave as regular mutable sets. Thus it is possible to manipulate sets after they are created, like so:

```
Set<Features> someFlags = EnumSet.noneOf(Features.class);
someFlags.add(FEATURE1);

someFlags.equals(flags); // true
someFlags.equals(requiredFlags); // false

someFlags.add(FEATURE2);

someFlags.equals(flags); // false
someFlags.equals(requiredFlags); // true
```

However, it is often a good idea to consider them immutable, and probably even wrap them in calls to [`Collections.unmodifiableSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-)

Since the `EnumSet` behaves as a regular set, performing set operations on it gives good ways of expressing membership, union, intersection and difference relationships.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yea, pushed save too quick. I'll add more info and example. Hang on.

Comment: I did read about enumset but couldn't really understand as how to use here. Also, using ordinal() makes it dependent on the order which does not seem to be  a good idea.

Comment: It will only be dependent on the order during the life time of the JVM, which is safe. YOU shouldn't depend on the order (unless you really know what you are doing, and not even then, preferrably :) ), but the JVM / JVM libraries are free to do so as long as the internal representation does not leak.

Comment: So, to toggle each flag i will have to invoke EnumSet.of() with the flag to be enabled as its argument?

Comment: Not necessarily, see updated answer :)

Comment: Ah! got it..but one more followup question - If i make them immutable i will not be able to add or remove from it I mean i need to mutate its state to toggle the flags.

Comment: True, you have to pick your poison :)

Answer (score 1):

use the BitSet class...
with that you can always get a well controlled relation between the flags you set and not

## Example:

```
final BitSet flags = new BitSet(); 
// set bit2/flag
flags.set(2);
// set bit15/flag
flags.set(15);

System.out.println("which flag did I set in flags: ");
System.out.println(flags);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with an EnumMap:

```
public class FlagMap {
    private enum Flags {
        FLAG1, FLAG2, FLAG3
    }

    private Map<Flags, Boolean> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new EnumMap<Flags, Boolean>(Flags.class));

    public void setFlag(Flags flag, boolean value) {
        map.put(flag, value);
    }

    public boolean getFlag(Flags flag) {
        return map.get(flag);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FlagMap flagMap = new FlagMap();
        // Set a flag:
        flagMap.setFlag(Flags.FLAG1, true);
        // Get a flag:
        System.out.println("Flag 1: " + flagMap.getFlag(Flags.FLAG1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a Map to name your flags in a single collection. e.g.

```
Map<String, Boolean> flags = new HashMap<>();
flags.put("flagName1", true);
flags.put("flagName2", false);

boolean flag1 = flags.get("flagName1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I have used a hybrid approach.
I have an enum say

```
private enum Flags{

    Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,Flag6;
}
```

Along with this i have used a bitset (`flagSet`).

Instead of setting hard coded index values in bitset i am taking the indices from Flags enum

```
flagSet.get(Flags.Flag1.ordinal()) //for getting
flagSet.set(Flags.Flag1.ordinal()) //For setting
```